# Silverlight Editable Combo Box

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I want to use comobox which is editable in my silverlight project, but silverlight doesnt provide a such control.
If any one knows how to create a custom editable combobox in silvelight 4.0 then please help me.

Editable combobox means:

1. A combo box providing list of
   options.
2. User can enter the value.
3. Filtering.

Comment: have you taken a look at the answers provided in the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178712/fixing-tim-heuers-editablecombobox-for-sl3-latest-sl-toolkit

Comment: Take a look in silverlight toolkit

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you are looking for the [AutoCompleteBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.autocompletebox%28VS.95%29.aspx).

- Allows user to type value
- Can simply dropdown like a combox
- Partial value typed can be used to filter choices using either StartsWith or Contains mode.
- Supports a create new entry operation if the final typed value does not match any existing entry

This control is part of the standard SDK and is found in the `System.Windows.Controls.Input.dll`.  You should be able to drag it from the toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look [Lookup Combo Box](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/Silverlight/Editors/combo-box.xml)